# Elastic Search update by query not reflecting correctly updated number of documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-java-api, resthighlevelclient

I am running an update by query call using the java rest client:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-update-by-query.html

This is my code: (extracted only the relevant part and updated some fields in the painless script)

```
UpdateByQueryRequest queryRequest = new UpdateByQueryRequest(indexName);
Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "if (ctx._source.someKey == someVal) {ctx._source.someKey = someOtherVal;}",Collections.emptyMap());
queryRequest.setScript(script);
BulkByScrollResponse bulkResponse = aesClient.updateByQuery(queryRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

The above code works fine, with the relevant documents getting updated. However Whenever I execute the following:

```
long updatedDocs = bulkResponse.getUpdated();
```

The value stored in `updatedDocs` doesn't reflect the actual number of documents getting updated. The value stored in it is the number of documents that it processed.

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-update-by-query.html#java-rest-high-document-update-by-query-response) , it should return the number of documents updated.

Please correct me if i am wrong. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your script to :

```
if (ctx._source.someKey == someVal) {ctx._source.someKey = someOtherVal;} else { ctx.op='noop'}
```

The ctx.op='noop' omits that document from its updates as specified in the [update_by_query documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

This no operation will be reported in :

```
long noops = bulkResponse.getNoops();
```